# Change value of a single input variabe to get out put results for each case the input single value is changed

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I would like to put random values like (s = 0.1, 0.7 , 0.4, 0.15, 0.18) to get the output results which are ( X and Rn ) for these values in different excel files or in the same excel file ,instead of putting them manually for each single code .How can I do that ? because i will have alot of s values so basically the only that changes is (s) which gives different solutions in each case, Kindly help if you can

```
ClearAll["Global"]
ClearAll[My`Print]
ClearAll[X1]
SetAttributes[My`Print, HoldAll]
My`Print[args___] := 
 Do[Print[Extract[Hold[args], i, HoldForm], "=", {args}[[i]]], {i, 
   Length[{args}]}]
s = 0.15; c = 2; k = (1/2)*(1 - a^2)*s^2; h = 10; n = 0.1; a = 
 n/(1 - n); 
p = -((Sqrt[(a*(1 - c)*y - 1)^2 - 2*(1 - 2*c)*(-(a*y) - k + y^2/2)] + 
       a*(1 - c)*y - 1)/(1 - 2*c)); 
f := (-(c*p + 1)^(-(1/c)))*(c*y + 1)^((1 - c)/c); NIntegrate[f, {y, 
  s, -s}]; 
\[Rho] = h/
  NIntegrate[
   f, {y, s, -s}]; rn = \[Rho]*(c*s + 1)^(1/c); rp = \[Rho]*(1 - 
     c*s)^(1/c); 
\[Delta] = rp - rn; My`Print[\[Rho], rn, rp, \[Delta]]
g = 
     -(1 - (c*(Sqrt[((a*(1 - c)*((y/\[Rho])^c - 1))/c - 1)^2 - 
             2*(1 - 2*c)*(-((a*((y/\[Rho])^c - 1))/c) + 
                             (1/2)*(((y/\[Rho])^c - 1)/c)^2 - 
                k)] + (a*(1 - c)*((y/\[Rho])^c - 1))/c - 1))/(1 - 
         2*c))^(-c^(-1)); 
R = 20; X = ({#1, 
     NIntegrate[g, {y, rn, (#1*\[Delta])/R + rn}] - h/2} & ) /@ 
  Range[R]; 
Rn = ({#1, (#1*\[Delta])/R + rn} & ) /@ Range[R]; 
XvsRn = Transpose[{Last /@ X, Last /@ Rn}]
ListLinePlot[(Callout[#1, Round[#1, 0.001] -> Point] & ) /@ XvsRn, 
 Mesh -> All, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red], 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#1, Black, 14] & ) /@ {"X", "Rn"}, 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
(Export["mfile1.xlsx", #1] & )[Prepend[{"X", "Rn"}][XvsRn]]
```

Comment: Define a function of s: `fun[s_]=...`

Comment: I tried it but the code doesn't work as the output is just for a single (s) value

Comment: f /@ {s1,s2,...} will give you a list of values for different s.